# Take the tag content in html code in a string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, parsing

I am writing tool for a OSINT project.
I have to state a site's html code string. In this code

I want to get the text between the tags.

```
$("p").text();
```

How can I make my variable applies to the string in the above code?

### I'm more open to good ideas...

solution:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: settings.wikiURL + settings.apiPath + "/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=" + settings.section + "&page=" + settings.page + "&callback=?",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    try {
                        var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
```

I would like to get the text between p tags which is veriable of markup

---

```
var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);

                        // remove links as they will not work
                        i.find('a').each(function () { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });

                        // remove any references
                        i.find('sup').remove();

                        // remove cite error
                        i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();

                        $('#article').html($(i).find('p'));
```

Comment: `$("p").text(yourvariable);` ?

Comment: in a string " $ ('p'). text (); " should be

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I would like to get the text between p tags which is veriable of markup

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

`var _html = $("p").text();`

And now _html is a var having the string stored.

Comment: I own html search. I'll search in a string.

Comment: in the string <p> I want to search

Comment: Like you want search if something exists in <p> or not?

Comment: I would like to get the text between p tags which is veriable of markup